# Data driven Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that takes uses a model called newsModels, this uses the IpagedList, however in the same view I have added a partial view that I want to list the 10 most recent news items added to the site, I want this partial view to be included in the newsitems view as well as on other views throughout the site.

What is the best way to do this.  I have only succeeded in listing the titles of the newsitems that the IpagedList is showing so not quite right still.

I assume I will need to create a separate controller for the partial view but I just cant find any guidance on how to do this.

can any one offer any advice / guidance

```
//Models
public class partialNewsMenu
   {
        public IEnumerable<NewsModels> newsTitle { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewsModels
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string newsTitle { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string newsDesc { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }

        public string addedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }
        public bool publishNewsItem { get; set; }
    }

//Controller
 public ActionResult OpsiumNews(string sortby, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.ImageName = "MSLOffice.jpg";
            ViewBag.ImageDesc = "Opsium News";
            ViewBag.OverlayText = "N/A";
            ViewBag.pageTitle = "Opsium News";
            ViewBag.Title = "Opsium | News";
            if (sortby == null)
            {
                ViewBag.MostRecent = "Selected";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.MostRecent = "";
            }          
            ViewBag.Oldest = "";
            ViewBag.PostedBy = "";
            ViewBag.ListNewsModels = new SelectList(db.NewsModels, "Id", "newsTitle");
             var NewsModelsList = db.NewsModels.Select(s => s.newsTitle);//.Where(s => s.publishNewsItem);


            var NewsModels = db.NewsModels.Where(c => c.publishNewsItem);
            switch (sortby)
            {
                case "1":
                    NewsModels = NewsModels.OrderBy(s => s.dateAdded);
                    ViewBag.MostRecent = "Selected";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    NewsModels = NewsModels.OrderByDescending(s => s.dateAdded);
                    ViewBag.Oldest = "Selected";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    NewsModels = NewsModels.OrderBy(s => s.addedBy);
                    ViewBag.PostedBy = "Selected";
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    NewsModels = NewsModels.OrderBy(s => s.dateAdded);
                    ViewBag.MostRecent = "Selected";
                    break;
            }
            ViewBag.currentsort = sortby;
            int pageSize = 1;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            return View("OpsiumNews", NewsModels.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

//View
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Opsium_website.Models.NewsModels>

@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="Sub-content" id="containcontent">
    <div class="rightSideHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-15 addBottomMargin">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("OpsiumNews", "UsefulInformation", FormMethod.Get))
                    {

                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {

                        <p>
                            Order by
                            <select name="sortby" id="sortby" onchange="submit();">
                                <option value="1" @ViewBag.MostRecent>Most Recent</option>
                                <option value="2" @ViewBag.Oldest>Oldest</option>
                                <option value="3" @ViewBag.PostedBy>Posted by</option>
                            </select>

                        </p>
                        <div class="col-md-9 addBottomMargin" id="contentText">
                            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.newsTitle)</h3>
                            <img src="~/Images/NewsImages/@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.imagePath)"  alt="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.newsTitle)" id="newsImage"/>
                            @MvcHtmlString.Create(item.newsDesc)
                            <p><b>Date Added:</b>@String.Format("{0:F}", item.dateAdded) - <b>Added By:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.addedBy)</p>
                        </div>
                        }
                    }
                    <div class="col-md-2 addBottomMargin" id="contentText">
                        @{Html.RenderPartial("_NewsTitlesList");} 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 addBottomMargin">
                        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

                        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("OpsiumNews",
                new { page, sortby = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Partial View
@model IEnumerable<Opsium_website.Models.partialNewsMenu>

@using PagedList.Mvc;
@foreach(var items in Model){
 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>items.newsTitle)

}
```

//error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[Opsium_website.Models.NewsModels]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Opsium_website.Models.partialNewsMenu]'.

Comment: You need to share your current code, current output and expected output.

Comment: Code and error has been added, thanks